# find mean of grouped data in RStudio~!

Tags: rstudio

[here is the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtPCc.jpg)
how to find the mean, median and mode of this grouped data by using RStudio?

Comment: Can you give examples of what you've tried?

Comment: ![Valid XHTML]http://i.stack.imgur.com/YtPCc.jpg

Comment: In your question, people aren't going to want to click on links.